# Setting up Knockd issues

Tags: firewalls, ubuntu, port-knocking

So i'm busy setting up a knockd service on a VM to enable SSH login when the correct sequence of ports are "knocked on" using knockd and ufw.

The issue that I am currently having is that when the correct sequence of ports are selected, the user.rules for ufw is not able to write the new rule to a file.

I have tried using chmod 777 on all files within /etc/ufw as a test, however the file is still not writable.

The output for /etc/ufw/user.rules is as follows:

```
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user6.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user6.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: ERROR: '/etc/ufw/user.rules' is not writable
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: openSSH: command returned non-zero status code (1)
```

The knockd file is shown in the code block below:

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = ufw allow 22/tcp
        tcpflags    = syn

[closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = ufw delete allow 22/tcp
        tcpflags    = syn
```

The output for /etc/default/knockd is shown below:

```
# control if we start knockd at init or not
# 1 = start
# anything else = don't start
# PLEASE EDIT /etc/knockd.conf BEFORE ENABLING
START_KNOCKD=1

# command line options
KNOCKD_OPTS="-i enp0s3"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using systemd disable (comment out or set explicit to off) ProtectSystem directive at knockd.service file (found in /lib/systemd/system/ folder).

If this works, reset it to full and put below it

```
ReadWritePaths=-/etc/ufw/
```

ProtectSystem=full mounts ro /usr, /boot and /etc for processes invoked by the unit excluding directories specified in ReadWritePaths.

If running, before restarting the service do

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```